# How to configure environment variables in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I have an application that gets deployed to Tomcat as a WAR file. I've externalized the properties in this application such that it reads the environment variable in tomcat to know where the configuration file is:

```
def exConfig = ((Context)(new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env"))).lookup("grailsExtConfFile")
```

The way I'm currently configuring this is by creating a file that has the same name as my war file (i.e. if `foo.war` then create `foo.xml`) in `../conf/Catalina/localhost/foo.xml

```
<Environment name="grailsExtConfFile" value="file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/configs.groovy" type="java.lang.String"/>

</Context>
```

All this works fine. However, each time I redeploy the above file gets deleted and I need to re-create it.

**Question**

Is there a way to configure this such that each time I re-deploy the file `foo.xml` does not get deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, maybe I'm not reading this right - why not place the configs outside tomcat ? say for e.g in /mnt/appconfig/foo-app/foo.xml - if this a NFS/SAN mount all nodes can read from it.